# Wso2 Scim 2.0 Connector Authentication Attribute

Tags: wso2, scim, scim2, wso2-identity-server

While I am trying to authenticate so that I can use Wso2 either through the panel or through API call I get this error:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} 
-  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : 
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException:
Mapped attribute cannot be found for claim : 
urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User:active in user store : PRIMARY
```

I don't want to add an additional field at my user store just for this. Is it possible to change authentication so that it does not look for `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User:active` in the user store?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you cannot login to the management console at all. Even as the admin user. Can you provide the following info.

1. What's the user store type (LDAP, JDBC, AD) ? Is it a read-only user store?
2. In the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+SCIM+2.0+Provisioning+Connector) there are 2 methods for configuring claims under **Configure claim dialects** section. Which method did you use ?